# MongoDB gui in python

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, mongodb

Is there any web MongoDB gui in python?
Or any linux os compatible gui?

Comment: Hello, I've released a new mongoclient written in javascript which is compatible on most Os. Here it's https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/milancermak/myngo : MongoDB Web front end written in python

plus a host of other options here : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs

Comment: This project is unmaintained since one year.

Comment: thanx.. not a big fan of Django.. but i will give it a try

Answer (score 2):

Try mongodb-admin - python command line : http://code.google.com/p/mongodb-admin/
I use this in "cloud'" to manipulate shards and replicas.

Comment: This link does not work anymore. Switch to: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/mongodb-atlas-appengineflex-nodejs-app

Answer (score 1):

[RockMongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo) is a php web based client that a lot of people like that's listed on the (outdated) Mongo GUI list.

[UMongo](http://edgytech.com/umongo/) is a non web-based desktop solution for Linux.

If you're using Eclipse [MonjaDB](http://www.jumperz.net/index.php?i=2&a=0&b=9) seems a nice plug-in - it's what I use, on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Look at

https://github.com/Fiedzia/Fang-of-Mongo/tree/fom_object/fangofmongo

which is more complete and maintained.